# How to take out props data from a component in react-js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-select

I am working on a react.js app with react-select using which I have made one dropdown menu and on click of an item in menu I want to pass that item to a function which is later connected to redux store.How can I access data from a component that is used in react-select?

Here's my code that will give you more reference.

```
const Option = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.Option {...props} >
      <div>{props.data.api}</div>
      <div style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{props.data.group}</div>
    </components.Option>
  );
};
```

The above code is my `Option` component which is used below to render a `Select Menu`.

```
return (
      <StyledForm id="form_container">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={3}>
              <input
                label="Client Name"
                value={this.props.clientName}
                onChange={this.setClientName}
              />
               <Select options={this.props.clientGrantList} components={{ Option }} onChange={()=>this.addApiGrants(//how to pass data)} />
            </Grid.Column>
```

This is my UI component where select menu is showing.

In the below Line in `addApiGrants` function I want to pass in select option data.How can I do it?

```
<Select options={this.props.clientGrantList} components={{ Option }} onChange={()=>this.addApiGrants(//how to pass data)} />
```

Thanks

Comment: does `this.props.clientName` not work from within that addApiGrants function?

Comment: there's nothing like clientName,its props.data.api and props.data.group.see in the Option function

Comment: Can you please share the version of react-select your using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onChange` handler function receives selected object as an argument. So, the code to handle this would be :

```
const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={options} onChange={item => addApiGrants(item)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how the selected `item` from `onChange` handler looks like

```
{value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry"}
```